# VS2013 debugger can not find Qt sources

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, qt5, visual-studio-debugging, qmake

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for building Qt5.3.1 projects. I use the express version so I don't use the VS plugin. My .vcxproj files a generated from .pro files using build scripts and qmake.

I installed Qt 5.3.1 with the default offline installation package that can be downloaded from the project pages. During installation I enabled sources to be installed (which are not installed by default).

When debugging my projects I sometimes try to step into Qt library code. This unfortunately does not work anymore (I know it once worked for some older Qt version but I can't name it). 
The .pdb files are found (I checked this in VS modules view) but the source files are not found. Whenever I step into Qt library code the debugger asks me to search the needed source file manually using a file dialog. If I select the proper .cpp file somewhere in the Qt folder the debugger works fine and I can step through the code. Unfortunately I need to repeat this for every Qt library source file and it is pretty annoying.

Is there a way to tell VS how to find the sources files in the Qt folder by itself?

Comment: Right-click the solution, Properties, Debug Source Files setting.

Comment: Great! That's what I searched for (at the wrong places). Please make this an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your VS, right click on the solution (in German: "Projektmappe"), then click on "Debug Source Files" (German: "Quelldateien debuggen") and add the needed source file directory.

Tipp: You can also use system environment variables (like "$(QTSRC)") here.